# npm not found from Visual Studio code terminal

Tags: npm, visual-studio-code

When I try to run "npm" from VS Code terminal, I get the error "The term 'npm' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or
operable program." This used to work in my previous laptop, so it seems I'm missing a configuration or extension?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please read the documentation on how to install npm and node on your machine: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/nodejs/nodejs-tutorial

Comment: You're right, while setting up my new environment I didn't install node.js

Answer (score 2):

If you have npm downloaded properly and still having this issue, simply close your VS code and re-open it. Solved it for me at least.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).